# remove and sum duplicate row in sql, can anyone give me insight for my query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, duplicates

My query are like this

```
SELECT
    A."name" AS so_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A."name") > 1
            THEN CONCAT('duplicate')
            ELSE CONCAT('is unique')
    END AS tags,
    e.total_qty AS sc_qty,
    (SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE(e.amount_total) * COALESCE (ai.base_currency_rate, 1))
     FROM account_invoice ai 
     JOIN invoice_sale_rel isr ON isr.invoice_id = ai.ID
     WHERE isr.sale_id = e.ID) AS sc_total
FROM 
    sale_quotation A 
JOIN 
    res_partner b ON b.ID = A.partner_id
JOIN 
    sale_order e ON e.quotation_id = A.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    res_users C ON C.ID = A.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    res_partner d ON d.ID = C.partner_id
WHERE 
    A.STATE != 'cancel'
    AND e.STATE != 'cancel'
    AND e.is_merchant = TRUE
ORDER BY 
    A.NAME ASC
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I am expecting the result would be like this, and add another values too

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    A."name" AS so_name,
    'is unique' AS tags,
    SUM(e.total_qty) AS sc_qty /*,
    (SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE(e.amount_total) * COALESCE (ai.base_currency_rate, 1))*/
     FROM account_invoice ai 
     JOIN invoice_sale_rel isr ON isr.invoice_id = ai.ID
     WHERE isr.sale_id = e.ID) AS sc_total
FROM 
    sale_quotation A 
JOIN 
    res_partner b ON b.ID = A.partner_id
JOIN 
    sale_order e ON e.quotation_id = A.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    res_users C ON C.ID = A.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    res_partner d ON d.ID = C.partner_id
WHERE 
    A.STATE != 'cancel'
    AND e.STATE != 'cancel'
    AND e.is_merchant = TRUE
GROUP BY
    A.NAME
ORDER BY 
    A.NAME ASC
```